# Java 11 to 14 migration - deserialization of Optionals with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, java-14

We're running a Java 11 application using Jackson for serialization. Until now we did not used the Jdk8Module. Nevertheless the (de)serialization worked fine. `Optional.empty()` got serialized as `'{ "value": null }'`.

After upgrading to Java 14 (de)serialization does not work anymore and we need to activate the Jdk8Module.

The problem is: after activating the Jdk8Module, Jackson excepts `'null'` for `Optional.empty()`, but all our JSON contains `'{ "value": null }'`. The result is that Jacksons did not recognize that the value is an `Optional.empty()` and passes the content to the specific serializer for the containing type ending in an exception.

We're looking for a smart solution to solve this problem.